# ListView onItemClick() not called on API 23 only

Tags: android, listview, android-6.0-marshmallow

My listview's onItemClick method is not being called when on API version 23. On version prior to that it's working great.

I've read about this issue [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&start=0&num=100&q=api%2023&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=-opened&id=213045) and it seems like it might relate. Any ideas?

The code is pretty straightforward, nothing fancy. It works on all version below API 23.

List item layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/history_member_A"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/history_item_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/operator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/history_item_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/history_member_B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/history_item_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/equal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=" = "
    android:textSize="@dimen/history_item_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/history_result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/history_item_text_size" />
```

The layout the list sits in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<keyboard.HistoryLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/history_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/history_height"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <keyboard.HistoryView
        android:id="@+id/history"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/history_height"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</keyboard.HistoryLayout>

public class HistoryView extends ListView implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    private HistoryAdapter mAdapter;

    public HistoryView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public HistoryView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public HistoryView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mAdapter = new HistoryAdapter();
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
        setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

    }

    public void loadHistory() {
        ArrayList<CalculationItem> items = CalcManager.getInstance().getHistoryItems();
        mAdapter.updateData(items);
    }

    public void update() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: The java code please ?

Comment: show your code for click event

Comment: added the code. the code inside the call is irrelevant - the method is not getting called

Comment: Use addOnItemClickListener instead setOnItemClickListener

Comment: Open new app, only list view in activity & report back.